# Torchvision transforms nomalize value selection

Tags: pytorch

This is the value for normalizing the kinetics dataset for video classification in the official script.
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/references/video_classification/train.py#L115

i.e.,

```
normalize = T.Normalize(mean=[0.43216, 0.394666, 0.37645],
std=[0.22803, 0.22145, 0.216989]).
```

And in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html
it says that “All pre-trained models expect input images normalized in the same way”
with this norm transform:
normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]).

My case is to use pre-trained resnet in `torchvision` to extract features on kinetics video frames.
So which norm should I choose?
And how these values come from?
Thanks.